# Ignoring a column in select query but need to use as a join condition

Tags: sql

Here i have this proc where i need to insert data into target table 4.In all these subqueries first_scan_issues/last_scan_issues/Prior_scan_issues where i need to join based on the scan_id but same time i should not use the scan_id in select query where the grouping result sets are splitting into more granularity.Even i tried with 'Partition by clause' it also gives more number of records. How can we avoid scan_id column and should use the same as join condition.
Target table 4

```
SOA_SECTOR                           VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) 
SOA_REGION                           VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) 
PROJECT                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(256 CHAR) 
SOLUTION                             VARCHAR2(256 CHAR) 
FIRST_SCAN_ISSUE_CNT        NOT NULL NUMBER(10)         
FIRST_FILES_WITH_ISSUES_CNT NOT NULL NUMBER(10)         
FIRST_SCAN_FILE_CNT         NOT NULL NUMBER(10)         
TOTAL_FILES_FOR_PROJECT_CNT NOT NULL NUMBER(10)         
LAST_SCAN_ISSUE_CNT         NOT NULL NUMBER(10)         
LAST_FILES_WITH_ISSUES_CNT  NOT NULL NUMBER(10)         
LAST_SCAN_FILE_CNT          NOT NULL NUMBER(10)         
PRIOR_SCAN_ISSUE_CNT        NOT NULL NUMBER(10)         
PRIOR_FILE_WITH_ISSUES_CNT  NOT NULL NUMBER(10)         
PRIOR_SCAN_FILE_CNT         NOT NULL NUMBER(10)         
LOAD_DATE_TIME              NOT NULL DATE
```

Proc

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table4
  SELECT first_scan_issues.SOA_SECTOR,
        first_scan_issues.SOA_REGION,
        a.PROJECT,
        a.SOLUTION,
        first_scan_issues.CNT1,             
       first_scan_issues.CNT2, 
       file_scans.CNT7, 
       project_files_count.COUNT,  
        last_scan_issues.CNT3,
        last_scan_issues.CNT4,
        file_scans.CNT8,
       prior_scan_issues.CNT5,
        prior_scan_issues.CNT6,
         file_scans.CNT9,     
        CURRENT_DATE
      FROM( select PROJECT,SOLUTION,FIRST_SCAN_ID,LAST_SCAN_ID,PRIOR_SCAN_ID from table1 order by project
      )a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       (
       select SOA_SECTOR,SOA_REGION,PROJECT,SOLUTION,SCAN_ID,
         COUNT(DISTINCT ISSUE_ID) CNT3,
        COUNT(DISTINCT FILE_ID) CNT4
        from table2 group by SOA_SECTOR,SOA_REGION,PROJECT,SOLUTION,SCAN_ID
        ) first_scan_issues on first_scan_issues.SCAN_ID = a.FIRST_SCAN_ID AND first_scan_issues.PROJECT =a.PROJECT
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (
      select SOA_SECTOR,SOA_REGION,PROJECT,SOLUTION,SCAN_ID,
         COUNT(DISTINCT ISSUE_ID) CNT3,
        COUNT(DISTINCT FILE_ID) CNT4
        from table2 group by SOA_SECTOR,SOA_REGION,PROJECT,SOLUTION,SCAN_ID
        )last_scan_issues ON last_scan_issues.SCAN_ID = a.LAST_SCAN_ID AND last_scan_issues.PROJECT =a.PROJECT
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (
      select SOA_SECTOR,SOA_REGION,PROJECT,SOLUTION,SCAN_ID,
         COUNT(DISTINCT ISSUE_ID) CNT3,
        COUNT(DISTINCT FILE_ID) CNT4
        from table2 group by SOA_SECTOR,SOA_REGION,PROJECT,SOLUTION,SCAN_ID
      ) prior_scan_issues ON PRIOR_scan_issues.SCAN_ID = a.PRIOR_SCAN_ID AND prior_scan_issues.PROJECT =a.PROJECT
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (
      select project,solution, count(distinct FIRST_SCAN_ID) CNT7, 
      count(distinct LAST_SCAN_ID) CNT8,count(distinct PRIOR_SCAN_ID) CNT9
      from table1 group by project,solution order by project
      )file_scans ON file_scans.PROJECT=a.PROJECT 
       JOIN
      (
       SELECT  PROJECT,SOLUTION,SOA_SECTOR,SOA_REGION,
       COUNT(DISTINCT PATH) COUNT
       FROM table3
       GROUP BY  PROJECT,SOLUTION,SOA_SECTOR,SOA_REGION                         
       ) project_files_count
       ON project_files_count.PROJECT = a.PROJECT;
END;
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  PROJECT       VARCHAR2(256 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  SOLUTION      VARCHAR2(256 CHAR),
  FIRST_SCAN_ID NUMBER(10)         NOT NULL,
  LAST_SCAN_ID  NUMBER(10)         NOT NULL,
  PRIOR_SCAN_ID NUMBER(10)         NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_tmp_first_last_scan_ids_id PRIMARY KEY (PROJECT)
);

CREATE TABLE table2
(
  ISSUE_ID         NUMBER(10)
    CONSTRAINT RPT_ISSUE_SUMMARY_PK
    PRIMARY KEY,
  SOA_SECTOR       VARCHAR2(128),
  SOA_REGION       VARCHAR2(128),
  USERNAME         VARCHAR2(128),
  PROJECT          VARCHAR2(256),
  SOLUTION          VARCHAR2(256),
  PATH             VARCHAR2(2048),
  TIME             DATE,
  CATEGORY         VARCHAR2(512),
  TITLE            VARCHAR2(512),
  ISSUE_IMP        VARCHAR2(256),
  CLICKED          NUMBER(3),
  SCAN_ID          NUMBER(10),
  SESSION_ID       NUMBER(10),
  RULEPACK_RULE_ID NUMBER(10),
  FILE_ID          NUMBER(10),
  FILE_INFO_ID     NUMBER(10),
  SCAN_YEAR_MON    VARCHAR2(7),
  SCAN_YEAR        VARCHAR2(4),
  SCAN_MONTH       VARCHAR2(2),
  LOAD_TIME        DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE table3
(
  SOA_SECTOR        VARCHAR2(128),
  SOA_REGION        VARCHAR2(128),
  USERNAME      VARCHAR2(128),
  PROJECT       VARCHAR2(256)  NOT NULL,
  SOLUTION       VARCHAR2(256),
  PATH          VARCHAR2(2048) NOT NULL,
  TIME          DATE           NOT NULL,
  LOC           NUMBER(10)     NOT NULL,
  SCAN_ID       VARCHAR2(256),
  SESSION_ID    VARCHAR2(256),
  FILE_ID       VARCHAR2(256),
  FILE_INFO_ID  VARCHAR2(256),
  SCAN_YEAR_MON VARCHAR2(7),
  SCAN_YEAR     VARCHAR2(7),
  SCAN_MONTH    VARCHAR2(7),
  LOAD_DATE_TIME     DATE           NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT rpt_scan_summary_pk PRIMARY KEY (SCAN_ID, FILE_ID)
)
```

Comment: Please try to minimize. Also post the structure of all tables (relevant in the minimized version of the problem), preferably as `CREATE TABLE` statements, along with sample data for all these tables (as `INSERT INTO` statements) and the desired result for that sample data (in some tabular text format).

Comment: Posted the create table structure for all the tables

Comment: Do you have any option to attach documents so that i'll attach all the statements